# Compressing JSON sent via CGI in Python

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest, cgi, gzip

The webApp I'm currently developing requires large JSON files to requested by the client, built on the server using Python and sent back to the client. The solution is implemented via CGI, and is working correctly in every way.
At this stage I'm just employing various techniques to minimize the size of the resulting JSON objects sent back to the client which are around 5-10mb ( Without going into detail, this is more or less fixed, and cannot be lazy loaded in any way).
The host we're using doesn't support mod_deflate or mod_gzip, so while we can't configure Apache to automatically create gzipped content on the server with .htaccess, I figure we'll still be able to receive it and decode on the client side as long as the Content-encoding header is set correctly.

What I was wondering, is what is the best way to achieve this. Gzipping something in Python is trivial. I already know how to do that, but the problem is:
**How do I compress the data in such a way, that printing it to the output stream to send via CGI will be both compressed, and readable to the client?**

The files have to be created on the fly, based upon input data, so storing premade and prezipped files is not an option, and they have to be received via xhr in the webApp.

My initial experiments with compressing the JSON string with gzip and io.stringIO, then printing it to the output stream caused it to be printed in Python's normal byte format eg: b'\n\x91\x8c\xbc\xd4\xc6\xd2\x19\x98\x14x\x0f1q!\xdc|C\xae\xe0  and such, which bloated the request to twice it's normal size...

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction here with how I could accomplish this, if it is indeed possible.
I hope I've articulated my problem correctly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use `print()` (which first converts its argument to a string before sending it to stdout) or `sys.stdout` (which only accepts str objects).

To write directly on stdout, you can use `sys.stdout.buffer`, a file-like object that supports bytes objects:

```
import sys
import gzip

s = 'foo'*100

sys.stdout.buffer.write(gzip.compress(s.encode()))
```

Which gives valid gzip data:

```
$ python3 foo.py | gunzip
foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Printing the output this way causes a 500 error while loading from the client, checking the server logs I find this:
    [Fri Apr 10 10:11:28 2015] [error] [client 172.17.240.5] malformed header from script. Bad header=\x1f\x8b\b: loader_main.cgi, referer: 

Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure exactly why this is occurring. It also seems that encoding the data as ascii is unsuitable as well, chrome expects the output to be served in proper binary to be valid.

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('Content-type: application/octet-stream\n\n') `

Comment: It was just an example. You still have to output headers first.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Even with valid headers attached you'll still get that error, which is the truly puzzling part. There's even the empty line after the header, so I have no idea why I'm getting a corrupt header error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers Valentin and Phillip! 
I managed to solve the issue, both of you contributed to the final answer. Turns out it was a combination of things.
Here's the final code that works:

```
    response = json.JSONEncoder().encode(loadData)  
    sys.stdout.write('Content-type: application/octet-stream\n')
    sys.stdout.write('Content-Encoding: gzip\n\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(gzip.compress(response.encode()))
```

After switching over to sys.stdout instead of using print to print the headers, and flushing the stream it managed to read correctly. Which is pretty curious... Always something more to learn.
Thanks again!